# Germs of a function (Tu differential geometry)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am currently learning differential geometry from Loring Tu An Introduction to Manifolds. I just want to know if my understanding is correct or not.

Given the statement below:

"As long as two functions agree on some neighborhood of a point p, they will have the same directional derivatives at p."

The reason this is true is because the directional derivative at the point p is just some number, so if they agree at certain nbhd, then when we calculate the directional derivative it should be the same. We could also see this geometrically as well.

If we draw small enough ball that both of functions agree on the ball, then the directional derivative is the same. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: No, your reasoning is incorrect.  The reason is that the directional derivative is defined as a limit, and that limit can be restricted to the n'hood surrounding the point $p$ in which the functions agree.

Comment: @g.s why is that possible ? Maybe can you add an answer explaining this ?

Comment: "so if they agree at certain nbhd, then when we calculate the directional derivative it should be the same. " This is more like an restatement of the statement you want to prove. I see no argument here...

Comment: See the definition here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative. 
 If the two functions agree in the n'hood, then in the definition select $h$ small enough so that $\mathbf{x}+h\mathbf{v}$ is always in the n'hood.  Then the difference quotient (and thus its limit, the directional derivative) will coincide for each function.

Comment: Alright, Yeah I understand it now. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a manifestation of the squeeze theorem.